# Giving error saying "unsupported graph driver: btrfs" in SLES when try to Kubeadm init

Tags: docker, kubernetes, sles

I try to install    Kuberneties cluster on SLES. But When I do Kubeadm init using below command it gives given error.

Kubeadm init

```
kubeadm init  --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --kubernetes-version=1.15.3
```

Error

```
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR SystemVerification]: unsupported graph driver: btrfs
    [preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

In SLES default file system is btrfs. So as per the official docker documentation [Get Docker EE for SLES](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ee/suse/)  I add below in /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
  "storage-driver": "btrfs"
}
```

So what would be wrong? Need your kind assistance.

*********************************EDITED*************************************

Docker Status

```
systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─flannel.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-08-22 17:21:59 CST; 1h 21min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 3188 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 24
   Memory: 52.9M
      CPU: 1.723s
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─3188 /usr/bin/dockerd --insecure-registry 192.***.***.***:***
```

Docker info

```
Containers: 2
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 1
Server Version: 18.09.4
Storage Driver: btrfs
 Build Version: Btrfs v4.9.1
 Library Version: 102
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
```

Docker-ee version.

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.4
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        c3516c4
 Built:             Wed Mar 27 18:11:35 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.4
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.8
  Git commit:       c3516c4
  Built:            Wed Mar 27 18:05:47 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

df -Th

```
/dev/mapper/data_vg-var            btrfs      **G  407M   **G   1% /var
/dev/mapper/data_vg-var_lib        btrfs      **G  232M   **G   1% /var/lib
/dev/mapper/data_vg-var_lib_docker btrfs      **G   17M   **G   1% /var/lib/docker
```

sudo cat /proc/filesystems | grep btrfs

```
# sudo cat /proc/filesystems | grep btrfs
    btrfs
```

Edited /etc/docker/daemon.json as below

```
{
  "storage-driver": "btrfs"
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Errors mostly occures when [prerequisites steps](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/) from documentation haven't been covered, so please check you have them all:

- install Docker EE
- btrfs requires a dedicated block device (such as a physical disk), which must be formatted for Btrfs and mounted into /var/lib/docker/
- btrfs support must exist in your kernel. To check this, run following command: `$ sudo cat /proc/filesystems | grep btrfs`
- you need the btrfs command. If you do not have this command, install the btrfsprogs package (for SLES)

Then please follow steps from **Configure Docker to use the btrfs storage driver** section and let me know if problem still exists.

Comment: I just edited the question. I just follow official docker documentation. But error still exit. PS: brtfs commands available in server.

Comment: Okay, also you can try using 'sudo' in 'kubeadm init' command. Temporary workaround for this issue is  'sudo kubeadm init --skip-preflight-checks'. I will look for another solution.

Comment: if anyone is having issues with `--skip-preflight-checks`, another command `kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=SystemVerification` worked for me for kubeadm 1.17.9-0. If using minikube, use `--extra-config=kubeadm.ignore-preflight-errors=SystemVerification` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue.

SLES uses btrfs by default. The docker “overlay” driver is not supported with this file-system, so it is sensible to use etx4 in /var/lib/docker.

Even if we tell Docker about BTRFS :

https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/

Kubeadm will still complain.

So use  use etx4 in /var/lib/docker.

Comment: Is this still an issue, or has k8s gotten better at it in the interim?