# How to install kubernetes in Suse Linux enterprize server 15 virtual machines?

Tags: kubernetes, suse

We are trying to install kubernetes in SUSE enterprize linux server v15. We found that there is no way to install k8s using kubeadm. SUSE provides Container as a service Platform(CaasP) to install k8s.

All we are having is few virtual machines and suse subscription. Can we install CaasP in it?
We could not find any documentation to install it in virtual machines.

Is there any way documentation to do step by step CaasP installation in Virtual machines?

Comment: Do you want to create cluster with `Master` and `Worker` nodes or you just want to try it? If you would like to try Kubernetes, did you consider to use `Minikube`? Minikube runs a single-node Kubernetes cluster inside a VM. Ive just deployed it on `SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP1` without any issues.

Comment: We have done K8s setup in other environments like ubuntu ,centos but in SLES only way to do is CaasP . We need info about that

Comment: What kind of VMs do you have? Are they cloud provider instances or VMs on on-premise hardware? What kind of hypervisor are you using? How do you install SLES 15: official VM images or custom installations? What kind of application are you planning to deploy on Kubernetes cluster? This information could help to make the answer shorter and better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Kubeadm on SLES

It is possible to install Kubernetes on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 using `kubeadm`.
You can find a step-by-step example below.

The example was tested on the following cloud VM images:

**GCP** :

- SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP1 x86_x64

**AWS** :

- openSUSE-Leap-15.2-v20200710-HVM-x86_64-548f7b74-f1d6-437e-b650-f6315f6d8aa3-ami-0f5745b812a5b7654.4 - ami-023643495f15f104b
- suse-sles-15-sp1-v20200615-hvm-ssd-x86_64 - ami-0044ae6906d786f4b

**Azure** :

- SUSE Enterprise Linux 15 SP1 +Patching

So, it has a good chance to be used with other images with only a few changes.

It was also tested on **Vagrant** box `trueability/sles-15-sp1` , and it was required a few additional steps, because of expired subscription keys. I used [OSS repositories](https://en.opensuse.org/Package_repositories) and ignored expiration errors:

```
# add OSS repository for software installation 
$ zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.2/repo/oss/ public

# add repository for installing newer Docker version

$ zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:containers/openSUSE_Leap_15.0/Virtualization:containers.repo virt

# install symbols required by Docker:

$ zypper install libseccomp-devel

# turn off all swap partitions. Comment appropriate /etc/fstab entry as well.

$ swapoff -a

# Rest of the steps is similar except additional argument during cluster initialization. 

# This box is using btrfs for /var/lib/docker and kubeadm complains about it. 
# I've just asked kubeadm to ignore that fact. 
# Even with btrfs it can start and run pods, but there might be some problems with Persistent Volumes usage, 
# so consider using additional xfs or ext4 partition for /var/lib/docker

$ kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --ignore-preflight-errors=all
```

#### Cloud VMs:

Cloud SLES 15 SP1 images uses xfs for their / file system and don't use swap out of the box, and kubeadm passes all pre-flight checks without errors.

```
# become root

$ sudo -s

# install docker

$ zypper refresh
$ zypper install docker

# configure sysctl for Kubernetes

$ cat <<EOF >> /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
EOF

# add Google repository for installing Kubernetes packages
#$ zypper addrepo --type yum --gpgcheck-strict --refresh https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64 google-k8s

#or

$ cat <<EOF > /etc/zypp/repos.d/google-k8s.repo
[google-k8s]
name=google-k8s
enabled=1
autorefresh=1
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
type=rpm-md
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
pkg_gpgcheck=1
EOF

# import Google repository keys

$ rpm --import https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
$ rpm --import https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
$ rpm -q gpg-pubkey --qf '%{name}-%{version}-%{release} --> %{summary}\n'

# the following repository was needed only for GCP image
# other images was able successfully install conntrack-tools using existing repository

$ zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:netfilter/SLE_12/security:netfilter.repo conntrack
$ zypper refresh conntrack

# conntrack presence is checked during kubeadm pre-flight checks 
# but zypper unable to find appropriate dependency for kubelet, 
# so let's install it manually

$ zypper install conntrack-tools

# refresh Google repository cache and check if we see several versions of Kubernetes packages to choose from

$ zypper refresh google-k8s
$ zypper packages --repo google-k8s

# install latest available kubelet package
# ignore conntrack dependency and install kubelet (Solution 2 in my case)

$ zypper install kubelet

# install kubeadm package. kubectl and cri-tools are installed as kubeadm dependency

$ zypper install kubeadm

# force docker to use systemd cgroup driver and overlay2 storage driver. 
# Check the links in the end of the answer for details. 
# BTW, kubelet would work even with default content of the file.

$ cat > /etc/docker/daemon.json <<EOF
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
EOF

# Not sure if it's necessary it was taken from the Kubernetes documentation

$ mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d

# lets start and enable docker and kubelet services

$ systemctl start docker.service
$ systemctl enable docker.service
$ systemctl enable kubelet.service

# apply configured earlier sysctl settings. 
# net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables becomes available after successfully starting
# Docker service 

$ sysctl -p

# Now it's time to initialize Kubernetes master node. 
# Ignore pre-flight checks for Vagrant box.

$ kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16

# prepare kubectl configuration to connect the cluster

$  mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
$  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
$  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

# Check if api-server responds to our requests. 
# At this moment it's fine to see master node in NotReady state.

$ kubectl get nodes

# Deploy Flannel network addon

$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

# remove taint from the master node. 
# It allows master node to run application pods. 
# At least one worker node is required if this step is skipped.

$ kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-

# run test pod to check if everything works fine

$ kubectl run nginx1 --image=nginx

# after some time... ~ 3-5 minutes

# check the pods' state 

$ kubectl get pods -A -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP           NODE        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default       nginx1                              1/1     Running   0          74s     10.244.0.4   suse-test   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-vc2x4            1/1     Running   0          2m26s   10.244.0.2   suse-test   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-w4jvq            1/1     Running   0          2m26s   10.244.0.3   suse-test   <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-suse-test                      1/1     Running   0          2m41s   10.4.0.4     suse-test   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-suse-test            1/1     Running   0          2m41s   10.4.0.4     suse-test   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-suse-test   1/1     Running   0          2m41s   10.4.0.4     suse-test   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-mbfxp         1/1     Running   0          2m12s   10.4.0.4     suse-test   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-cw5xm                    1/1     Running   0          2m26s   10.4.0.4     suse-test   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-suse-test            1/1     Running   0          2m41s   10.4.0.4     suse-test   <none>           <none>

# check if the test pod is working fine

# curl 10.244.0.4
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
...skipped...

# basic Kubernetes installation is done
```

#### Additional materials:

- [Container runtimes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) (Kubernetes documentation page)
- [Giving error saying “unsupported graph driver: btrfs” in SLES when try to Kubeadm init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589205/giving-error-saying-unsupported-graph-driver-btrfs-in-sles-when-try-to-kubead)
  (If you have `btrfs` **/** partition, you can mount additional `xfs` or `ext4` partition for `/var/lib/docker` to use `overlay2` Docker storage driver)
- [OverlayFS support for SLES 12](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019184) (I would expect that SLES 15 support it as well.)
- [Docker Compatibility Matrix](https://success.docker.com/article/compatibility-matrix)

  ```
    OS Distribution (x86_64): SLES 15
    Enterprise Engine: 19.03.x
    UCP: 3.2.x
    DTR: 2.7.x
    Storage Driver: overlay2,btrfs
    Orchestration: Swarm mode, Kubernetes
    DTR Storage Backend: NFSv4, NFSv3, Amazon S3, S3 Compliant Alternatives, 
                Azure Storage (Blob), Google Cloud Storage, OpenStack Swift, 
                Local Filesystem
  ```
- [SUSE: Docker Open Source Engine Guide](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP1/pdf/book-sles-docker_color_en.pdf) (very useful book)
- [Use the OverlayFS storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/)
- [Install Linux Kernel 4.12 in openSUSE](https://ostechnix.com/install-linux-kernel-4-12-opensuse/) (in case you want to add AUFS support to the Linux kernel)

#### Materials about SUSE CaaSP

- [SUSE CaaS Platform Setup - Nothing to Everything in 1 Hour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAKfexcX8lE)
  (video is quite old but very useful)
- [CaaSP download page, 60 days free trial](https://www.suse.com/products/caas-platform/download/)