# Kubernetes on SuSE: NodePort Service Problems

Tags: kubernetes, opensuse, suse

for days I'm trying to track down a weird behaviour concerning NodePort Services when running Kubernetes on openSUSE Leap 15.3.

For testing purposes on my own server I installed 3 VMs with openSUSE 15.3. With this article: [How to install kubernetes in Suse Linux enterprize server 15 virtual machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62795930/how-to-install-kubernetes-in-suse-linux-enterprize-server-15-virtual-machines) I set up this Kubernetes Cluster:

```
kubix01:~ # k get nodes -o wide
NAME      STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION         CONTAINER-RUNTIME
kubix01   Ready    control-plane,master   25h   v1.22.2   192.168.42.51   <none>        openSUSE Leap 15.3   5.3.18-59.27-default   docker://20.10.6-ce
kubix02   Ready    <none>                 25h   v1.22.2   192.168.42.52   <none>        openSUSE Leap 15.3   5.3.18-59.27-default   docker://20.10.6-ce
kubix03   Ready    <none>                 25h   v1.22.2   192.168.42.53   <none>        openSUSE Leap 15.3   5.3.18-59.27-default   docker://20.10.6-ce
```

For testing things out I made a new 3 Replica Deployment for a traefik/whoami Image with this yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: whoami
  labels:
    app: whoami
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: whoami
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: whoami
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: whoami
        image: traefik/whoami
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

This results in three Pods spread over the 2 worker nodes as expected:

```
kubix01:~/k8s/whoami # k get pods -o wide
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE   IP           NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
whoami-8557b59f65-2qkvq   1/1     Running   2 (24h ago)   25h   10.244.2.7   kubix03   <none>           <none>
whoami-8557b59f65-4wnmd   1/1     Running   2 (24h ago)   25h   10.244.1.6   kubix02   <none>           <none>
whoami-8557b59f65-xhx5x   1/1     Running   2 (24h ago)   25h   10.244.1.7   kubix02   <none>           <none>
```

After that I created a NodePort Service for making things available to the world with this yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: whoami
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: whoami
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30080
```

This is the result:

```
kubix01:~/k8s/whoami # k get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          25h
whoami       NodePort    10.105.214.86   <none>        8080:30080/TCP   25h

kubix01:~/k8s/whoami # k describe svc whoami
Name:                     whoami
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=whoami
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.105.214.86
IPs:                      10.105.214.86
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30080/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.1.6:80,10.244.1.7:80,10.244.2.7:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

So everything looks fine and I tested things out with curl:

1. curl on one Cluster Node to PodIP:PodPort

```
kubix01:~/k8s/whoami # curl 10.244.1.6
Hostname: whoami-8557b59f65-4wnmd
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 10.244.1.6
RemoteAddr: 10.244.0.0:50380
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.244.1.6
User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
Accept: */*

kubix01:~/k8s/whoami # curl 10.244.1.7
Hostname: whoami-8557b59f65-xhx5x
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 10.244.1.7
RemoteAddr: 10.244.0.0:36062
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.244.1.7
User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
Accept: */*

kubix01:~/k8s/whoami # curl 10.244.2.7
Hostname: whoami-8557b59f65-2qkvq
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 10.244.2.7
RemoteAddr: 10.244.0.0:43924
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.244.2.7
User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
Accept: */*
```

==> Everything works as expected

2. curl on Cluster Node to services ClusterIP:ClusterPort:

```
kubix01:~/k8s/whoami # curl 10.105.214.86:8080
Hostname: whoami-8557b59f65-xhx5x
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 10.244.1.7
RemoteAddr: 10.244.0.0:1106
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.105.214.86:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
Accept: */*

kubix01:~/k8s/whoami # curl 10.105.214.86:8080
Hostname: whoami-8557b59f65-4wnmd
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 10.244.1.6
RemoteAddr: 10.244.0.0:9707
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.105.214.86:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
Accept: */*

kubix01:~/k8s/whoami # curl 10.105.214.86:8080
Hostname: whoami-8557b59f65-2qkvq
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 10.244.2.7
RemoteAddr: 10.244.0.0:25577
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.105.214.86:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
Accept: */*
```

==> Everything fine, Traffic is LoadBalanced to the different pods.

3. curl on Cluster Node to NodeIP:NodePort

```
kubix01:~/k8s/whoami # curl 192.168.42.51:30080
Hostname: whoami-8557b59f65-2qkvq
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 10.244.2.7
RemoteAddr: 10.244.0.0:5463
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.42.51:30080
User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
Accept: */*

kubix01:~/k8s/whoami # curl 192.168.42.52:30080
^C [NoAnswer]
kubix01:~/k8s/whoami # curl 192.168.42.53:30080
^C [NoAnswer]
```

==> NodePort Service is only working at the same Node, no answer from the other nodes

4. curl from another Network Host to NodeIP:NodePort

```
user@otherhost:~$ curl 192.168.42.51:30080
^C [NoAnswer]
user@otherhost:~$ curl 192.168.42.52:30080
^C [NoAnswer]
user@otherhost:~$ curl 192.168.42.53:30080
^C [NoAnswer]
```

==> Service is not reachable from the outside at all, no answer on all nodes

Has anybody an idea what is going wrong here?

Thx in advance

T0mcat

PS:
Additionally here a little image for clearing things a bit more. Red curved arrows are the non - working connections, gree curved arrows the working ones:

[image: diagram]

Comment: IMO, for anything to be accessible from outside the cluster; you need to use loadbalancer service type.

Comment: Hello @T0mcat Are you able to `ping` from your master node to worker nodes? Could you add some information about your VMs - how did you create them, details about network?

Comment: your SDN doesn't work, check on the SDN Pods, in the kube-system namespace.

Comment: @PrateekJain: Not as far as I understood the K8s service thing. NodePort services opens ports (3000 - 327...) on the real network IP of every Node, so that this service is available externally at all, which is a prerequisite for using an external LoadBalancer, of course.
A Service Type "LoadBalancer" works on top of Service Type "NodePort" and is responsible for automatically configuring such an external LoadBalancer and is mostly used in cloud envs, as AWS, Google aso.

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin:
Yes, the nodes can ping each other... another test was using netcat on an arbitary Port 31337 on two nodes, which works, too. So IMHO this is not a network related issue...my thoughts r going to somthing with kube-proxy / iptables

Comment: @SYN:
What do u mean exactly with "SDN Pods"? The Pod Network Addon, which in this case is flannel? These pods r running... and what is more, the pods can communicate to each other on their pod IPs without problems.

Comment: @All
I tested the whole setup with Ubuntu (so debian based) VMs, did the same debian related things as I did in openSUSE for setting up a K8s Cluster. 
I deployed the identical YAML Files to this cluster and the NodePort Service works completely as expected... it is reachable from the outside and each node can reach the service on each node IP
So IMHO this must be sth. special in openSUSE, isn't it?

Comment: @T0mcat, even in that case client needs to know external IP of node.

Comment: @PrateekJain Sure... but in my case this setup is a PoC for testing purposes in my own LAN only. It is not meant to be opened to the Internet, which would be done with the help of some sort of external LoadBalancer, which can be reached from the Internet, of course. 
But when I use another PC/VM in the LAN for "external" connection tests, for K8s point of view I AM the client and so I know the "external" IPs of the nodes (which are 192.168.42.51/52/53 as described in the first post).

Comment: can you try this example, it might help https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/

Comment: @PrateekJain Just tried the "PortForwarding to Service" Part of this link, which didn't work. Quit logical... the "kubctl port-forwarding ...." opens up a port just on localhost, not the LAN interface. 
As a plus, this is running as own process in the foreground so it can't be meant to be sth to use for real K8s driven apps. 
I'm wondering what the use case for this PortForwarding could be.. perhaps some sort of troubleshooting... quickly accessing a service from a dev machine with kubectl installed on it maybe.

Comment: Anything suspicious from the output of `kubectl logs -n kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-proxy`?

Comment: Can you advise what network plugin are you using and did you configured it in a specific way (non-default)? From the diagram it seems traffic on the host network (LAN) cannot route into the k8s cluster network.

Comment: @gohm'c The network plugin used is flannel, not configured. Just used "--pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16" during kubeadm init.
Did I get it correctly, that the network plugin (flannel) is responsible for building the inter - pod net with new network interfaces (named "flannel1.1" and "cni0" in my case) on the nodes? And everything dealing with services is realized by kube-proxy and a bunch of iptables entries it creates? So as pod to pod and pod to service communication ist completely working, could flannel be the correct direction?

Comment: Beside cluster network, flannel also provide the "bridge" between the overlay network that it created and your host network (LAN). Do you see anything suspicious `kubectl logs -n kube-system -l app=flannel`?

Comment: @gohm'c No, nothing suspicious in kub-proxys logs... just these deprecated warnings: " warnings.go:70] discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1 EndpointSlice is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+; use discovery.k8s.io/v1 EndpointSlice"

Comment: how about flannel log? `kubectl logs -n kube-system -l app=flannel`

Comment: @gohm'c In the flannel logs there r a couple of entries about adding / deleting iptables rules
`I1012 14:48:18.667970       1 iptables.go:172] Deleting iptables rule: ! -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.244.0.0/24 -j RETURN `
....
`I1012 14:48:18.769447       1 iptables.go:160] Adding iptables rule: ! -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.244.0.0/24 -j RETURN
I1012 14:48:18.771498       1 iptables.go:160] Adding iptables rule: ! -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.244.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE --random-fully
`
....

Comment: can you try `cat /run/flannel/subnet.env`?

Comment: FLANNEL_NETWORK=10.244.0.0/16
FLANNEL_SUBNET=10.244.0.1/24
FLANNEL_MTU=1450
FLANNEL_IPMASQ=true

Comment: What do you see on the host `cat /run/flannel/subnet.env`

Comment: yesterday I answered this ;)
This is the content:
FLANNEL_NETWORK=10.244.0.0/16
FLANNEL_SUBNET=10.244.0.1/24
FLANNEL_MTU=1450
FLANNEL_IPMASQ=true

Comment: A little new detail...after setting up the cluster with the steps from the above mentioned StackOverflow Article, immediatly creating the whoami - pods and NodePort Service, everything works fine.
BUT:
When the Nodes are rebooted, the service doesn't work anymore as described, despite every (kube-system) pod is running ...

Answer (score 1):

FINALLY found the solution:

Weird behaviour of SUSE concerning ip_forward sysctl setting. During OS Installation the Option "IPv4 forwarding" was activated in the installer. After OS was installed, additionally added "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" and
"net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1" in /etc/sysctl.conf.
With "sysctl -l|grep ip_forward" checked, both options where activated but this obviously wasn't the truth.
Found the file "/etc/sysctl.d/70-yast.conf"... here both options where set to 0, which obviously was the truth. But manually setting these options to 1 in this file still weren't enough...
Using SUSEs YAST tool and entering "System/Network Settings" -> Routing one can see the Option "Enable IPv4 Forwarding", which was checked (remember: in 70-yast.conf these options where set to 0). After playing a bit with the options in YAST, so that the 70-yast.conf gets rewritten and both options where set to 1 in 70-yast.conf, NodePort services are working as expected now.

Conclusion:

IMHO this seems to be a Bug in SUSE... Activating "IPv4 Forwarding" during Installation leads to a 70-yast.conf with disabled forwarding options. And as a plus, "sysctl -l" displays wrong settings, so as YAST does...
The solution is to play around in YASTs network Settings, so that 70-yast.conf gets rewritten with activated ip_forwarding options.